# Podemos usar {variavel} nas Views do CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-tags

Sei que podemos usar Views arquivo.html no CodeIgniter, agora gostaria de saber se podemos usar tags `{variavel}` diretamente como no Smarty.

Exemplo:

```
<body>
  <h1>{msg}</h1>
</body>
```

Existem alguma função nativa de substituição? Ou tem que usar mais um framework acoplado?

Gostaria de separar completamente o PHP do HTML, hoje eu já faço isso com uma classe própria, mas gostaria de saber se o CodeIgniter já faz isso.

A titulo de exemplo na substituição:

```
$data = array();
$CI = & get_instance();
$page = $CI->load->view('login.html', $data, true);
echo   str_replace("{teste}", "Hello World", $page);
```

Comment: O codeigniter não vem com nenhum template engine. Trocar `<?php echo $msg; ?>` por `{$msg} ` nativamente não é possível!

Comment: Eu trabalho com o CI, mas até onde eu sei, é preciso adaptar para que ele reconheça estas variáveis. Nunca tentei usar, sempre uso $var->campo;

Comment: Só a titulo de exemplo vejam as linhas:

$data = array();
            $CI = & get_instance();
            $page = $CI->load->view('login.html', $data, true);
            echo   str_replace("{teste}", "Hello World", $page);

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione essa informação. Você não comentou nada antes de substituições. Eu não acho nada prático esses `str_replace()` ...

Comment: De fato o str_replace é só a título de demonstração, deve ter uma meio mais amigável

Comment: Me desculpem pessoal é meu primeiro post no stack vou pegar o jeito do editor pra formatar melhor.

Comment: Você pode editar o código da pergunta com o botão `{ }` ou identando cada linha de código com 4 espaços :)

Comment: [Aqui tem umas orientações de edição](/editing-help)

Comment: @rray acho que é o parser, conforme foi respondido, hein

Answer (score 2):

O codeigniter tem uma library de parser para isso que precisa, da uma olhada http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html

E para fins de deixar aqui como seria é algo assim:

```
// carrega a library
$this->load->library('parser');

// le/gera os dados
$data = array(
            'blog_title' => 'My Blog Title',
            'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading'
        );

// carrega a view blog_template e passa os dados
$this->parser->parse('blog_template', $data);
```

e a view ficaria algo como:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{blog_title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>{blog_heading}</h3>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Essa lib está disponível apenas na versão 3 do CI? +1 pela resposta tbm

Comment: não, a versão 2 já tinha e não me lembro se a versão 1.* já tinha também.

Comment: Consegui achar o [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html) da documentação do CI2, é a primeira vez que vejo alguem comentar sobre essa lib.

Comment: muito provável porque quem começa a usar percebe que ela é mais lenta para renderizar tudo no final e é bem básica, mas dependendo para o que for quebra um galho.